# CollectionView is not working fine "cellForItemAt" method swift

Tags: swift, tableview, collectionview

I have one collectionView and TableView is my collectionViewCell.
I have Question Title in my collectionView and answer options in my TableView.
I have some database method which I am doing on select of tableView method means in my "didSelectRowAt" method.
Problem is If I am trying to insert from collectionView "CellForItemAt" method someWhere index problem is coming. Means I am not getting correct data.

[image]

Here below is my Code :-

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "QuestionsCell", for: indexPath) as! QuestionsCell

    cell.Test = self.test
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.labelQuestion.text = Questions[indexPath.row].questionTitle
    cell.question = Questions[indexPath.row]
    cell.questionID = Questions[indexPath.row].questionID

        if checkSelected {
            Helper.sharedInstance.Print("Answer Is Selected" as AnyObject)
        }

        else {
          //Helper.sharedInstance.Print(Questions[indexPath.row].questionID as AnyObject)
          cell.saveSkippedAnswer()
        }
    }

    func saveSkippedAnswer() {
        if !(fetchQuestionSelected.count > 0) {
             saveSelectedOptionCalculation(indexSelected: "skipped", questionID: question!.questionID!, testID: Test!.testID!)
        }
    }


//MARK :- CollectionView Flow layout
extension QuestionViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    //thisWidth = CGFloat(self.view.frame.width)
    return CGSize(width: self.collectionView.bounds.width, height: self.collectionView.bounds.height)
  }

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
  }
}. 

fileprivate func setUpCollectionView() {
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    //collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
    collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
    collectionView.bounces = false
    collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(flowLayout, animated: true)
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout
    self.collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "QuestionsCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "QuestionsCell")
    self.collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: SomeTimes is not called when cell constraint is not good or may be cell size is not proper

Comment: Constraints is fine I guess. 
How should I do ?

Comment: Are you using flowlayout or not

Comment: Yes I am using flowLayout.

Comment: can you add storyboard screen shot with constraint

Comment: issue is occurring while you dequeuing CollectionView and tableView are you sure the source array you are using are synced , like question 3 at point 3 in array and related answer to that respected que are also at same point 3 ?

Comment: Yes Array in Synced . But Problem is coming for visible index Path .
Sometimes it gives previous one (right Side Scrolling).

Comment: I have edited my question Please check it. 
Thanks